# Cómo llenar AlertDialog Multichoice con datos de webservices

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, alertdialog

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Buenas tardes

Pues bueno, mi problema y duda es rápida, tengo un `AlertDialog` en mi `ActionBar`, el cual necesito que sea multichoice.

Lo que requiero es llenar ese `AlertDialog` con un `arraylist`, pero mis datos yo los obtengo desde un Webservice, estoy implementando la clase `Assynctask` para hacer la llamada del método y en el mismo `doInbackground` lleno mi `arraylist`, solo me falta saber como llenar ese arraylist que tengo a mi `AlertDialog`, y que cuando el usuario seleccione una opción en mi `activity` me arroje el resultado.

Dejo código de mi `AlertDialog`:

```
 public void EligirZona() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Clientes.this);
    {

        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("ONC_Settings", 0);
        AsyncZona task = new AsyncZona(settings.getString("ONControlWSURL", "").toString());
        //Call execute
        task.execute();

        // Boolean array for initial selected items
        final boolean[] checkedColors = new boolean[]{
                false, // Norte
                true, // Sur
                false, // Metropolitana
        };

        // Convert the color array to list
        // final List<String> colorsList = Arrays.asList(colors);

        String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
        zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);


        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(zona, checkedColors, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                // Update the current focused item's checked status
                checkedColors[which] = isChecked;

            }
        });

        builder.setCancelable(false);

        // Set a title for alert dialog
        builder.setTitle("Selecciona la Zona(s) que Visitaras");

        // Set the positive/yes button click listener
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click positive button
            /*tv.setText("La Zona Seleccionada es..... \n");
            for (int i = 0; i<checkedColors.length; i++){
                boolean checked = checkedColors[i];
                if (checked) {
                    tv.setText(tv.getText() + colorsList.get(i) + "\n");
                }
            }*/
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"La Zona Seleccionada es", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            }
        });

        // Set the negative/no button click listener
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click the negative button
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Set the neutral/cancel button click listener
        builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // Do something when click the neutral button
            }
        });

        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
        // Display the alert dialog on interface
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```

clase `AsyncZona` que uso para llamar al método:

```
private class AsyncZona extends AsyncTask<String, ArrayList, ArrayList>
    {
        private String ONControlWSURL;
        public AsyncZona(String ONControlWSURL)
        {
            this.ONControlWSURL = ONControlWSURL;
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected ArrayList doInBackground(String... params) {
        ZonaArrayList = new ArrayList<Zona>();
        webService O_WS = new webService(ONControlWSURL);
        ZonaArrayList=O_WS.Zona();
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
        super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

        if(ZonaArrayList.size()!=0){

            /*Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.menu_spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<FormaPago> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<FormaPago>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, PagoArrayList);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);*/

        }else{

        }
    }
}
```

Método que uso para tomar los datos:

```
public ArrayList<Zona> Zona()
    {
    String resultado = "";
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(ONControlWSNameSpace, "CatalogoGeneral");
    request.addProperty("Id", 0);
    request.addProperty("Clave", "");
    request.addProperty("Descripcion", "");
    request.addProperty("FiltroAdicional", "");
    request.addProperty("Catalogo", "sp_zona");

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.implicitTypes = false;
    // Set output SOAP object
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // Create HTTP call object
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(ONControlWSURL, 7000);

    ArrayList<Zona> ZonaArray = new ArrayList<Zona>();

    try {
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        // Invoke web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(ONControlWSNameSpace+"CatalogoGeneral", envelope);
        SoapObject SO_Zona = (SoapObject)((SoapObject)((SoapObject) envelope.getResponse()).getProperty(1)).getProperty(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < SO_Zona.getPropertyCount(); i++) {

            Zona newDetalle = new Zona(ONC_SYS.NullToZeroInteger(webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Id", (SoapObject) SO_Zona.getProperty(i))),
                    webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Clave", (SoapObject) SO_Zona.getProperty(i)),
                    webService.WSGetPropertyNull("Descripcion", (SoapObject) SO_Zona.getProperty(i)));


            ZonaArray.add(newDetalle);


        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Assign Error Status true in static variable 'errored'
        //menu.errored = true;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //Return booleam to calling object
    //return loginStatus;

    return ZonaArray;


}
```

agrego mi clase Zona es donde guardo mis objeto

public class Zona {

```
private int Id;
private String Clave;
private String Descripcion;
/*private String FiltroAdicional;
private String Catalogo;*/

public Zona(int Id, String Clave, String Descripcion)
{
    super();
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Clave = Clave;
    this.Descripcion = Descripcion;
    /*this.FiltroAdicional = FiltroAdicional;
    this.Catalogo = Catalogo;*/
}

public int getId() {return Id;}

public String getClave() {return Clave;}

public String getDescripcion() {return Descripcion;}

public String toString() {
    return Descripcion;
}
```

}

Dialogo que lleno en el OnpostExecute

@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList arrayList) {
            super.onPostExecute(arrayList);

```
        if(ZonaArrayList.size()!=0) {

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Selecciona Zona que Visitaras");
            //builder.setMessage("Selecciona la Zona(s) que Visitaras");
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Zona>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, ZonaArrayList);


            builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

                }
            });
            builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do something
                }
            });;
            builder.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });

            AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();

           // adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Zona>(context, android.R.layout.select_dialog_multichoice, ZonaArrayList);

            /*Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.menu_spinner1);
            ArrayAdapter<FormaPago> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<FormaPago>(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, PagoArrayList);
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);*/

        }else{
```

Logcat

```
06-03 10:43:15.837 1536-1536/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 729K, 32% free 5102K/7428K, paused 7ms, total 7ms
06-03 10:43:15.889 1536-1536/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-03 10:43:15.897 1536-1536/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=262, eventTime=1057598, downTime=1039632, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
06-03 10:43:16.025 1536-1536/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile W/EGL_genymotion: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
06-03 10:43:16.029 1536-1536/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=264, eventTime=1057700, downTime=1039632, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
06-03 10:43:16.029 1536-1536/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=265, eventTime=1057752, downTime=1039632, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }
06-03 10:43:16.205 1536-1536/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.
06-03 10:43:16.209 1536-1536/mx.com.oncontrol.oncontrolmovile W/ViewRootImpl: Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT, scanCode=100, metaState=META_ALT_ON|META_ALT_RIGHT_ON, flags=0x8, repeatCount=269, eventTime=1057958, downTime=1039632, deviceId=1, source=0x301 }

                                                                              [ 06-03 10:43:16.405    64:   64 D/         ]
                                                                              Socket deconnection

                                                                              [ 06-03 10:43:18.421    64:   64 D/         ]
                                                                              Socket deconnection

                                                                              [ 06-03 10:43:20.429    64:   64 D/         ]
                                                                              Socket deconnection

                                                                              [ 06-03 10:43:22.441    64:   64 D/         ]
                                                                              Socket deconnection

        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: he visto el código, ZonaArray  es en realidad un array de objetos Zona, agrega la definición de tu objeto por favor y agrego una respuesta! =)

Comment: listo ya la agregue, ya he tratado de hacerlo de mil maneras pero no me sale :(

Comment: Evita editar tu pregunta para colocar "solución". En su lugar, acepta la respuesta que más te ayudó a resolver el problema. Si ninguna te ayudó en particular, publica una nueva respuesta y luego la aceptar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ZonaArray` es en realidad un array de objetos `Zona`, lo que se tiene que obtener es la "Descripcion", para mostrar las opciones en el Dialogo:

```
   ...
    ...
    ...

        String[] zona = new String[ZonaArrayList.size()];
        //zona = ZonaArrayList.toArray(zona);   
        for(int i=0; i<ZonaArrayList.size(); i++){
              //Obtiene el campo Descripción y lo agrega al array de strings "zona".
             zona[i] = ZonaArrayList.get(i).getDescription(); 
        }

        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(zona, checkedColors, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {

                    // Update the current focused item's checked status
                    checkedColors[which] = isChecked;

                }
            });
 ...
...
...
```

Al tener tu arreglo zona con los datos de descripción, ahora se podrá llenar tu Dialogo con los textos.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40730/discussion-on-answer-by-elenasys-como-llenar-alertdialog-multichoice-con-datos-d).